# Email using smtp not working when deployed in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am using following code for sending email using smtp gmail , Its works on my machine but when I deployed on azure its not working.

```
 try
        {
            // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress( "k4@gmail.com","From Name");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("mghazanfar@hotmail.co.uk", "To Name");
            const string fromPassword = "Meabana";
             string subject = "Feedback for Comic Maker from " + Request["name"];
             string body = Request["message"]+"\n\n\n\n\n\n";
             body += Request["email"];
             body += Request["phone"];


            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message1 = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message1);
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email sent successfully')", true);
                email.Value = "";
                phone.Value = "";
                name.Value = "";
                message.Value = "";
            }
        }
        catch {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Some problem occurred')", true);
        }
```

I got this error
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: Are you receiving some sort of error?

Comment: I got this error The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at.

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan, Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: No i didn't solve this.